# Convert computed property for @State for Swiftui Views

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

I'm new with SwiftUI and i want to convert basically my computed property for being used in SwiftUI views with combine and all that. I couldn’t use it like that because "get set" doesn't work for my SwiftUI views and I kinda struggled here.
Maybe someone has a good solution how can i convert it with with combine to use in swift ui.

Storage service saves the Authdata into userdefaults.

```
var currentAuthData: AuthData? {
    get {
        return self.storageService.get(AuthData.self, forKey: authDataStorageKey)
    }
    set {
        if let value = newValue {
            self.storageService.store(value, forKey: authDataStorageKey)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "`get set` doesn't work for my SwiftUI views" -- How so? You Syntax-wise, it doesn't necessarily look like you have anything wrong here. Can you include enough code for a [mre] and explain how the result you're seeing is different from what you expect?

Comment: Tough to help out without a more information. A common mistake is to place state in the View. In SwiftUI Views are structs and are reinstantiated as often as once per frame (100 times per second). Make sure to keep state in an ObservableObject and pass it into Views: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-user-interface-state.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you would turn a computed property in SwiftUI, by making it a @propertyWrapper. I have added a solution to read the data using Combine if you need it. I also make you property optional.

- I assume this is the model you want to save.

```swift
struct AuthData {

  var name: String
  var email: String
}
```

- Prepare the protocol for your property wrapper to be able to be set to nil using Optional.

```swift
public protocol AnyOptional {
  var isNil: Bool { get }
}

extension Optional: AnyOptional {
  public var isNil: Bool { self == nil }
}
```

- Extend UserDefaults to conform to this protocol and be optional.

```swift
extension UserDefault where Value: ExpressibleByNilLiteral {

  init(key: String, _ container: UserDefaults = .standard) {
    self.init(key: key, defaultValue: nil, container: container)
  }
}
```

- Create the property wrapper that is the same thing as a getter and setter for SwiftUI views. This is a generic one and can be use to any type. You can set them in the UserDefaults extension after this bloc of code.

```swift
import Combine

@propertyWrapper
struct UserDefault<Value> {
  let key: String
  let defaultValue: Value
  var container: UserDefaults = .standard

  // Set a Combine publisher for your new value to
  // always read its changes when using Combine.
  private let publisher = PassthroughSubject<Value, Never>()

  var wrappedValue: Value {
    get {
      // Get the new value or nil if any.
      container.object(forKey: key) as? Value ?? defaultValue
    }
    set {
      // Check if the value is nil and remove it from your object.
      if let optional = newValue as? AnyOptional, optional.isNil {
        container.removeObject(forKey: key)
      }
      else {
        // Set your new value inside UserDefaults.
        container.set(newValue, forKey: key)
      }
      // Add the newValue to your combine publisher
      publisher.send(newValue)
    }
  }
  var projectedValue: AnyPublisher<Value, Never> {
    publisher.eraseToAnyPublisher()
  }
}
```

- Create the extension in UserDefaults to use your property wrapper in your code.

```swift
extension UserDefaults {

  @UserDefault(key: "authDataStorageKey", defaultValue: nil)
  static var savedAuthData: AuthData?

  // You can create as many @propertyWrapper as you want that fits your need
}
```

**examples of use**

```swift
// Set a new value
UserDefaults.savedAuthData = AuthData(name: "Muli", email: "muli@stackoverflow.com")

// Read the saved value
print(UserDefaults.savedAuthData as Any)

// When using combine
var subscriptions = Set<AnyCancellable>()

UserDefaults.$savedAuthData
  .sink { savedValue in
    print(savedValue as Any) } // Yours saved value that changes over time.
  .store(in: &subscriptions)
```

Comment: don't store auth data in user defaults (not secure). name and email are PII

Comment: You are right, but it was set here as an example of using UserDefaults with SwiftUI.